# ScrollViewer not scrolling when attempting to scroll while SIP is visible in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard, sip, scrollviewer

I'm having trouble getting ScrollViewer with item-bound text boxes to scroll when the keyboard is up. I'm also clueless about enumerating the textboxes so that I can create a Tab like functionality when Enter key is pressed to move between the input fields. I looked at some of the tutorials online and they don't seem to work.

I need to drop the keyboard before choosing another TextBox to actually input information. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the SIP to close when the user touches 'Enter' with some code in the KeyUp event.

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Height='72'
           Name='textBox5'
           Text=''
           Width='460'
           KeyUp='textBox5_KeyUp' />
```

**Code**

```
private void textBox5_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

  // to force the SIP to close on enter key
  if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
  {
    // be sure and set IsTabStop = true on root element
    this.Focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: That'll be helpful but my problem is that the Textboxes are generated inside an itemtemplate, and I want Enter to shift between various textboxes. is there a way to order them to pick a sequential tabstops so that they behave like they're supposed to?

Comment: Also, any ideas on how to make them scrollable all the way to the bottom of the ApplicationPage when the SIP is up?

Comment: You really have three questions here... :>

Comment: You can set the tab stops in the itemtemplate.  IsTabStop="True" TabIndex="5"

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for the scrollable question.

Comment: thanks, but all the questions are related to the same problem - I was just asking about different workarounds.